# Every torsion free divisible abelian group D is direct sum of the copies of the $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, divisible-groups

> Prove that every torsion free divisible abelian group $D$ is direct sum of the copies of the $\mathbb{Q}$.

If $a\in D$ then there exists unique $b \in D$  and $n\neq 0 \in \mathbb{Z} $ such that a=nb. Now, D is torsional free means that every element except identity is not of finite order. b can be written as b= 1/n a but I am unable to think which result should I use now?

Can you outline a complete proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some hints, if you can answer these, you should have your proof.

1. What is another name for modules over the ring $\mathbb{Z}$?
2. What is another name for modules over the ring $\mathbb{Q}$?
3. What structural theorems do we know about $\mathbb{Q}$-modules?

Comment: I don't know the answers of 1 and 2. My class notes don't cover alternative names of such modules. I request you to outline a proof. Can you please do that?

Comment: Sure, a module over $\mathbb{Z}$ is another definition of abelian group, and being a torsion free divisible abelian group $A$ is exactly the structure we need to put a $\mathbb{Q}$ module on $A$. This is another name for a $Q$ vector space structure on $A$, so torsion free abelian groups are just vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}$. Then every vector space has a basis, which is exactly expressing it as a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Q}$.